# How to represent a scaling object?

Tags: transparency, color-theory, texture, perception

This is a subjetive question, however I can imagine there are answers with reasoning so I think it fits the website.

I'm designing a visualization tool in a static medium (no animations) for 2D objects which undergo transformations over time. At the moment, I'm dealing with representing how an object scales (increases or decreases in size).
By researching, I came across the concept of *Isochron maps* (figure bellow):

[image: Isochron map]

The problem is two-fold:

**1. How to represent the direction of scale?**
The example shown above does so using color gradients with a legend. What are the approaches, using visual variables like color, transparency or texture, to perceive the direction of scale without a legend, if any?
For example, my first try using transparency had no success (figure bellow). I used the same opacity for each object state but if I scale down or up the result is the same, because of how transparency blends (I'm using Three.js).

[image: Transparency]

**2. How to deal with non-uniform scaling?**
In the first example shown, you can see the object always growing. However, how would someone represent an object that sometimes shrinks and other times grows? Without giving it any though, the colors would overlap and it would be difficult to perceive each object state.

Comment: In your first example the transparency only interacts with the map below it, not with the other data colors. That might be a clue.

Comment: @Luciano That is correct. However that alone can't solve the problem: if we draw each state behind the previous we'd get the effect from the first example, but if an object decreases size in a state then it would be covered by the previous state...

Comment: This is too ambiguous of a request for us to help tangibly. What's your use case?

Comment: also your second question is not possible to represent using the transparency model: what should happen when two regions overlap (in case an object shrinks on one direction but grows on another)? How do you see both colors?

Comment: I do not use Three.js but in Illustrator I would use solid colors, group them and apply transparency to the group to reveal the map below. Is there something similar in Three.js?

Comment: @LeoNas I'm new to Three.js, I'll have to look it up, but thank you for the tip.

Comment: For the second problem (Also using Illustrator), we can use Offset Path. It adds an offset equally in every direction.

Comment: @LeoNas Unfortunately, as this is for scientific visualization the data (vertices) can't be modified.